# Updating sprite positions from gyroscope parameters in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, gyroscope

I'm trying to update the position of an image sprite in cocos2d by using pitch, roll, and yaw values from gyroscope(like in the iphone app 'skyview'). How can do that? I just want the relation between X and Y positions and the 3 parameters(pitch, roll and yaw).

If the code is too big please give me some links from where I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: elaborate what are the pitch, roll and yaw values??

Comment: @rptwsthi  Those are the rotation angles of the gyroscope.  CMDeviceMotion *currentDeviceMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion;      
        CMAttitude *currentAttitude = currentDeviceMotion.attitude;     mypitch = currentAttitude.pitch;  myroll = currentAttitude.roll;  myyaw = currentAttitude.yaw;